# wxPython and virtualenv on OS X

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, pip, virtualenv

Right now Im using OS X Yosemite and trying to install in my virtuaenv few packages via `pip`:

```
relrin at MacBook-Relrin in ~ 
=> cd code/Helenae/

relrin at MacBook-Relrin in ~/code/Helenae 
=> source bin/activate

relrin at MacBook-Relrin in ~/code/Helenae workon code 
=> pip install wxPython wxPython-common
Downloading/unpacking wxPython
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement wxPython
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external wxPython to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for wxPython
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/savicvalera/.pip/pip.log

relrin at MacBook-Relrin in ~/code/Helenae exited 1 workon code 
=> pip install --allow-external wxPython wxPython-common
Downloading/unpacking wxPython-common
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement wxPython-common
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external wxPython-common to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for wxPython-common
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/savicvalera/.pip/pip.log
```

Few minutes ago trying install via brew:

```
brew install wxPython
```

But installed not in virtualenv, installed in the main user directory.
How can I fix this? Cause [wxPyWiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/) doesn't working right now, and i can't look at docs, how to use virtualenv and wxPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

1) Install via brew:

```
   brew install python --framework
   brew install wxPython
```

2) Make virtualenv when you want

3) Go to your site-packages directory in your virtualenv and add symbol links:

```
cd <there your path to lib/python2.7/site-packages/ in virtualenv>
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx* .
```